# dygraphs: Skip missing values in bar chart

Tags: dygraphs

I am trying to

- plot a bar chart
- with categorial data
  (only plot existing x values/labels)
- (bonus: automatically resize canvas to include leftmost and rightmost bar completely)

however dygraphs scales the x axis according to the input values and I have lots of unwanted white space.

**What I would expect** would be something like [image: categorial display from R/ggplot2]

(no extra space between bars)

**instead I get**:

[image: unwanted dygraphs behaviour: missing times still displayed]

**my HTML/dygraphs source**:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var example_data = "time,idx_cpu_avg\n"+
"2015-07-24 10:40:05,37.0229\n"+
"2015-07-24 10:41:35,11.6869\n"+
"2015-07-24 12:03:15,37.0358\n"+
"2015-07-24 12:04:05,11.4845\n"+
"2015-07-24 13:36:38,36.8488\n"+
"2015-07-24 13:37:24,11.2219\n"+
"2015-07-27 18:30:40,36.859\n"+
"2015-07-27 18:31:29,11.3381\n"+
"2015-07-28 06:28:14,110.215\n"+
"2015-07-28 06:29:01,26.5677\n"

function barChartPlotter(e) 
{
  var ctx = e.drawingContext;
  var points = e.points;
  var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);  // see http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomYCoord

  // This should really be based on the minimum gap
  var bar_width = 2/3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
  ctx.fillStyle = e.color;

  // Do the actual plotting.
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

    ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
        bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
    ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
        bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>index values as bar chart (skipping missing values)</h2>
    <div id="graphdiv4"
      style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      g2 = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv4"),
        example_data,
        {
            plotter: barChartPlotter, // barChartPlotter,
            connectSeparatedPoints: false
        }          // options
      );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As danvk suggested, you should rename columns with values 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. to force the even spacing that you want. You then

have to suppress this value from the legend and set the x-axis `axisLabelFormatter` to generate the value that you want to be displayed instead of 0, 1, 2, 3.
Same for `valueFormatter` method, in order to display the correct value in the legend.

Here is the code:

```
axes: {
      x: {
        valueFormatter: function(x) {
          switch (x) {
            case 1:
              return 'Corresponding string';
              break;
            case 2:
              return 'Corresponding string';
              break;
            case 3:
              return 'Corresponding string';
              break;
            case 4:
              return 'Corresponding string';
              break;
            default:
              return '';
           }
         },
         axisLabelFormatter: function(x) {
           switch (x) {
             case 0:
               return 'Corresponding string';
               break;
             case 1:
               return 'Corresponding string';
               break;
             case 2:
               return 'Corresponding string';
               break;
             case 3:
               return 'Corresponding string';
               break;
             ...
             default:
               return '';
           }
         }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to add a new column with values 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. to force the even spacing that you want. You'd have to suppress this value from the legend and set the x-axis `axisValueFormatter` to generate dates instead of 0, 1, 2, 3.

If this sounds like too much work, you might find it easier to generate this particular chart with a more general tool like D3.